# Deploy CoreOS virtual machine on vSphere with Terraform

Tags: terraform, coreos, vsphere

I'm having a really difficult time trying to deploy a CoreOS virtual machine on vsphere using Terraform.

So far this is the terraform file I'm using:

```
# Configure the VMware vSphere Provider. ENV Variables set for Username and Passwd.

provider "vsphere" {
 vsphere_server = "192.168.105.10"
 allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

provider "ignition" {
  version = "1.0.0"
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "Datacenter"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "vol_af01_idvms"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name          = "Cluster_rnd/Resources"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "VM Network"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = "coreos_production"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

# Create a folder
resource "vsphere_folder" "TestPath" {
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
  path       = "Test"
  type       = "vm"
}

#Define ignition data
data "ignition_networkd_unit" "vmnetwork" {
  name  = "00-ens192.network"

  content = <<EOF
  [Match]
  Name=ens192
  [Network]
  DNS=8.8.8.8
  Address=192.168.105.27/24
  Gateway=192.168.105.1
EOF
}

data "ignition_config" "node" {
  networkd = [
    "${data.ignition_networkd_unit.vmnetwork.id}"
  ]
}

# Define the VM resource
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
 name   = "terraform-test"
 folder = "${vsphere_folder.TestPath.path}"
 resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
 datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"

 num_cpus = 2
 memory   = 1024
 guest_id = "other26xLinux64Guest"

 network_interface {
   network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
 }

 disk {
    name             = "terraform-test.vmdk"
    size             = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size}"
    eagerly_scrub    = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub}"
    thin_provisioned = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned}"
  }

 clone {
    template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"
  }

 extra_config {
    guestinfo.coreos.config.data.encoding = "base64"
    guestinfo.coreos.config.data          = "${base64encode(data.ignition_config.node.rendered)}"
  }
}
```

I'm using terraform vsphere provier to create the virtual machine and ignition provider to pass customization details of the virtual machine such as network configuration.

It is not quite clear to me if I'm using correctly the *extra_config* property on the virtual machine definition. You can find documentation about that property [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#extra_config).

Virtual machine gets created, but network settings never are applied, meaning that ignition provisioning is not correctly working.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly configure Terraform for this particular scenario (Vsphere environment and CoreOS virtual machine), specially regarding [guestinfo](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/vmware-guestinfo.html) configuration.

- Terraform v0.11.1, provider.ignition v1.0.0, provider.vsphere v1.1.0
- VMware ESXi, 6.5.0, 5310538
- CoreOS 1520.0.0

Comment: A good starting point is to output the rendered ignition config to see if it is what's expected. If guidance is needed on how to do that, reach out.

Comment: @DanCat I already did that and the file is correct. Based on [this](https://github.com/coreos/tectonic-installer/issues/1729#issuecomment-323556282) comment from github, I suspect that my problem is related to that vApp option setting that I can't uncheck (it's missing in my virtual machines due to the fact that we don't own the appropriate VMware license). I sent an email to VMware support explaining my situation and I'm waiting for an answer.

Comment: How do you roll out changes to ignition config?

Comment: @Dhawal I use Terraform Ignition provider https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/ignition/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT (2018-03-02)**

As of version 1.3.0 of terraform vsphere provider, there is available a new  [vApp](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/pull/303) property. Using this property, there is no need to tweak the virtual machine using VMware PowerCLI as I did in the first answer.

There is a complete example of using this property [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/tree/master/examples/ovf-template)

The machine definition now would look something like this:

```
  ...

  clone {
    template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"
  }

  vapp {
     properties {
        "guestinfo.coreos.config.data.encoding" = "base64"
        "guestinfo.coreos.config.data"          = "${base64encode(data.ignition_config.node.rendered)}"
  }

  ...
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Finally got this working.

The workflow I have used to create a CoreOS machine on vSphere using Terraform is as follows:

1. Download the latest Container Linux Stable OVA from
   https://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/current/coreos_production_vmware_ova.ova.
2. Import `coreos_production_vmware_ova.ova` into vCenter.
3. Edit machine settings as desired (number of CPUs, disk size etc.)
4. Disable "vApp Options" of virtual machine.
5. Convert the virtual machine into a virtual machine template.

Once you have done this, you've got a CoreOS virtual machine template that is ready to be used with Terraform.

As I said in a comment to the question, some days ago I found [this](https://github.com/coreos/tectonic-installer/issues/1729#issuecomment-323556282) and that lead me to understand that my problem could be related to not being able to perform  step 4.

The thing is that to be able to disable "vApp Options" (i.e. to see in the UI the "vApp Options" tab of the virtual machine) you need DSR enabled in your vSphere cluster, and, to be able to enable DSR, your hosts must be licensed with a key that supports DRS. Mine weren't, so I was stuck in that 4th step.

I wrote to VMware support, and they told me an alternate way to do this, without having to buy a different license.

This can be done using VMware PowerCLI. [Here](https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2017/04/powercli-install-process-powershell-gallery.html) are the steps to install PowerCLI, and [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI651/html/index.html) is the reference. Once you got PowerCLI installed, this is the script I used to disable "vApp Options" in my machines:

```
Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI

#connect to vcenter
Connect-VIServer -Server yourvCenter -User yourUser -Password yourPassword

#Use this to disable the vApp functionality.
$disablespec = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineConfigSpec
$disablespec.vAppConfigRemoved = $True

#Use this to enable
$enablespec = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineConfigSpec
$enablespec.vAppConfig = New-Object VMware.Vim.VmConfigSpec

#Get the VM you want to work against.
$VM = Get-VM yourTemplate | Get-View

#Disables vApp Options
$VM.ReconfigVM($disablespec)

#Enables vApp Options
$VM.ReconfigVM($enablespec)
```

I executed that on a Powershell and managed to reconfigure the virtual machine, performing that 4th step. With this, I finally got my CoreOS virtual machine template correctly configured for this scenario.

I've tested this with terraform vSphere provider versions v0.4.2 and v1.1.0 (the syntax changes) and the machine gets created correctly; Ignition provisioning works and everything you put on your ignition file (network configs, users etc.) is applied on the newly created machine.